# Retrieve data from Firebase into an entity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from Firebase database to add it to local database.

This code :

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myRef = database.getReference();     
Query LANGUAGES_REF = myRef.child("languages").orderByChild("id");

LANGUAGES_REF.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {    
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                       do {
                           Language language = iterator.next().getValue(Language.class);
                           languageR.insert(language);
                          } while (iterator.hasNext());
               }
```

is not working , and I know it's because Language.class is an entity. 
Is there a way other than creating a new class with getters and setters and full constructor ...   and repeating everything??

The error I got was:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object
>   of type java.lang.Long to type
>   com.android.android.Database.Entities.Language

at this line :

```
Language language = iterator.next().getValue(Language.class);
```

Thanks

edit: 
firebase database structure

```
"languages" : {
    "LHZ7cAeOdPn-LwHNjIk" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "langName" : "Russian"
    },
    "LHZ7cAtXTGBlnWsdQOd" : {
        "id" : 2,
        "langName" : "French"
    },
    "LHZ7cAvrRs0rgI-PaJd" : {
        "id" : 3,
        "langName" : "Turkish"
    }
}
```

language.class

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity
public class Language implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    private String langName;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getLangName() {
        return langName;
    }

    public Language(String langName) {
        this.langName = langName;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: Please also add the entire code that you are using to get the data, including the reference on which you are attaching the listener. Please responde with a comment, once you added the code.

Comment: Sorry for posting little info earlier, actually, I did create a languageCast class and its working fine, the question now is, was there another solution using the Entity language.class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, you need to remove the `do-while` loop because there is no need to iterate using `getChildren()` method, you can get the data directly from the `dataSnapshot` object like this:

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
    Language language = dataSnapshot.getValue(Language.class);
    languageR.insert(language);
    Log.d(TAG, language.getLangName());
}
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
Russian
French
Turkish
```

Comment: now i'm a getting a 
      `Database.Entities.Language does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped. `

I added a no argument constructor,  and an  `@Ignore` annotatin and it's working fine ... 

Thanks a million @alexmamo